# How to bypass "stack level too deep (SystemStackError)" Error

Tags: ruby

(using OS X 10.9.4) I have this cool `Ruby` script which scans system/firewall logs and tells me if anything odd is happening. The script runs on a 1 second loop, however at exactly the `3852nd iteration`, the script terminates with a `"stack level too deep (SystemStackError)"` error.

I am not new to this error and it seems to appear when a script enters a loop, and the system sandbox (probably) terminates it after a set amount of time or a specific parameter is reached.

I attempted to bypass the error by running the script as root, however this had no effect. I have also considered programming another script to relaunch the original script when it detects its absence in the command: `ps -ef`s' output, however this is a very 'clunky' method which i would prefer to avoid.

I have also conducted some research into the error on the "Stack Overflow", however only found questions answered by altering the offending script ,as the error is in their case due to a bug in the code, which is not the case for me.

So my question:

**Is there any possible way to bypass the "stack level too deep (SystemStackError)" error**

Thanks in advance, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using recursion, not loops - hence the issue. Ensure that your recursive method has a way to get out and not keep calling itself forever

Comment: Yes, @WandMaker is correct. If you post a link to your script we can probably point out a way to restructure the script as needed. Also *"as the error is in their case due to a bug in the code, which is not the case for me."* == famous last words of a programmer ;)

Comment: You are using recursion. There is no cap explicitly set (like Python's `sys.setrecursionlimit()`) in Ruby if that is what you are asking. Just rewrite the script to use regular iteration.

Comment: haha "famous last words" == "good advice". Yeah that makes sense, i have a series of interweaved functions which simply recur, its actually not a loop, my bad. I will investigate your suggestions, thanks.